# Best way of developing RESTfully service with dot net

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I know we can develop the RESTfull service with ASP.Net API, WCF and Now ASP.Net MVC 4 API also we can develop by MVC 3/4 which can return JSON data that can be easily invoke by mobile app...same like REST.

Now big confusion is in which scenario I should choice which technology.

Please provide the proper technical answer...that will help me lot...

Thanks in advance....

Thanks

Afazal

Comment: I think you need to understand what REST means before you can make a good judgement. Just because something returns JSON doesn't mean it is REST. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I know what is REST. If we answer to the point that will be great help..

Comment: Isnt that your choice. Depends on your knowledge and own preferences. Restful design is independent of technology. Personally I used AngularJS on top of a WCF Service app through cross doamin.

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want to create a RESTful application you will want to go with either Web API or WCF with the WebHttpBinding class if you want to use Microsoft technology.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.webhttpbinding(v=vs.110).aspx

While mvc can be made to be restful it isn't as natural a fit as Web API. WCF has more complexity than Web API and so from what you have said so far you should pick Web API.